What can we say when a module of differential is free?
Let $\mathbb{C}$ complex number.
$R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f)(f\in \mathbb{C}[x,y])$
If the module of differential $\Omega_{R/\mathbb{C}}$ is free $R$ module of rank one,
what can we say about $R$.
How far is $R$ from the affine line?
For example, is $R$ an integral domain?
In particular, I'm interested its de Rham cohomology.
Does its first cohomology group vanish?
Here is the definition of de Rham cohomology of rings.
http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1975__45__5_0/

If the curve $f=0$ is smooth (which is the case if $f$ is general), then $\Omega ^1_{R/\mathbb{C}}$ is free of rank 1, with generator $dx/f'{y}=-dy/f'{x}$ (note that $f'{x}$ and $f'{y}$ do not vanish simultaneously on $f=0$). And $H^1_{dR}$ is usually nonzero.

I'm considering the case $\Omega$  is free , not locally free.

In my example $\Omega$ is free — I give a generator.

Does  $\Omega$ contain $\frac{dx}{f'_y}$?
Now I'm considering a module of differential, not sheaf of differential.

$f'_x, f'_y, f$ are coprime so there are $a, b, c\in\mathbb{C}$ with $af'_x+bf'_y=1$ in $R$. So you can write the $1$-form $dx/f'_y=-dy/f'_x$ also as $bdx-ady$.

Sorry, typo: I meant $a, b\in\mathbb{C}[x, y] $
